# Why does .textAlligment only works if its placed after .defaultTextAttribute?

Tags: swift

Why does text alignment property does not work if its declared before .defaultTextAttribute bunch of code? It didn't throw any run-time errors but its property never changed or did any effect.

I have the following code working:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Setting the delegates
    self.upperTextField.delegate = self
    self.lowerTextField.delegate = self
    // Default text of textFields
    upperTextField.text = "Up"
    lowerTextField.text = "Down"
    // Default text Attributes
    let textAttributes = [
        NSStrokeColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40)!,
        NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: 0
    ]
    upperTextField.defaultTextAttributes = textAttributes
    lowerTextField.defaultTextAttributes = textAttributes
    // Align text
    upperTextField.textAlignment = .Center
    lowerTextField.textAlignment = .Center
}
```

I got it working when I changed

```
// Align text
    upperTextField.textAlignment = .Center
    lowerTextField.textAlignment = .Center
```

after // Default text attributes

Im using Xcode 7.3 and swift 2.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: From the docs `defaultTextAttributes` Setting this property applies the specified attributes to the entire text of the text field. **Unset attributes maintain their default values.**

Comment: Try passing the desired aligment NSTextAlignment in your textAttributes dictionary

Comment: So It does changed but it returns to its default state after textAttributes is set?

Comment: Add  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName To your dictionary with the desired aligment

Comment: Yes it uses the default if you don't set it. The default it is probably  left aligment

Comment: Anyone know what to add to the dictionary? Nothing seems to work. Like `NSTextAlignment` (which throws an error because you can't use `.rawValue` on it, and therefore isn't a **String**), and like `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName`, which doesn't even seem to exist.